# UITextField working in iPhone XR, but not in iPhone 7 (Xcode Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am unable to get UITextField to accept an input in iPhone 7 simulator. The code works fine in iPhone XR simulator. What is missing?

Full code below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var containerView = UIView()

    var textFieldFirstNameSignUp: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size

        let width = screenSize.width - 60

        let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 80, width: width, height: 26))
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 32)
        titleLabel.text = "Create New Account"
        self.containerView.addSubview(titleLabel)

        self.scrollView = UIScrollView()
        self.scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:1000, height:1000)

        containerView = UIView()
        scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        containerView.addSubview(titleLabel)

        textFieldFirstNameSignUp = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 140, width: width, height: 50))
        textFieldFirstNameSignUp.placeholder = "First Name"
        textFieldFirstNameSignUp.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        self.containerView.addSubview(textFieldFirstNameSignUp)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()  
        scrollView.frame = view.bounds
        containerView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: scrollView.contentSize.width, height: scrollView.contentSize.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: What's happening in the simulator that differs from the iPhone XR?

Comment: I copied your exact code into a test project.  I was able to type into the first name text field in both the 7 and XR simulators.  Maybe restart Xcode and the simulator?  Anyway, good job on using  programmatic layout.

Comment: I have restarted everything including the mac, have done clean build and still no luck. What is bizarre is that the code is not working for iPhone 7, but works in all other models including 6, 7 Plus, X, XR, etc.